# Installing chromium-browser on Debian Wheezy Depends: chromium (>= 10) but it is not installable

Tags: debian, apt, chrome

On FriendlyARM mini210s

```
# uname -a
Linux mini210s 3.0.8-FriendlyARM #2 PREEMPT Mon Feb 25 14:25:10 HKT 2013 armv7l GNU/Linux

# more /etc/debian_version
7.8
```

When running the package manager

```
# apt-get install chromium-browser
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 chromium-browser : Depends: chromium (>= 10) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

and

```
# apt-cache show chromium-browser
Package: chromium-browser
Version: 37.0.2062.120-1~deb7u1
Installed-Size: 1693
Maintainer: Debian Chromium Maintainers <pkg-chromium-maint@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: all
Replaces: chromium (<< 13.0.782.215~r97094-1)
Depends: chromium (>= 10)
Breaks: chromium (<< 13.0.782.215~r97094-1)
Description-en: Chromium browser - transitional dummy package
 Chromium is an open-source browser project that aims to build a safer, faster,
 and more stable way for all Internet users to experience the web.
 .
 Chromium serves as a base for Google Chrome, which is Chromium rebranded (name
 and logo) with very few additions such as usage tracking and an auto-updater
 system.
 .
 This package contains the Chromium browser transitional dummy package.
Homepage: http://www.chromium.org/Home
Description-md5: a3cca84948c287f5c01b8b5e9f7e67ed
Tag: implemented-in::c, implemented-in::c++, interface::web, interface::x11,
 protocol::http, role::dummy, role::program, uitoolkit::gtk,
 use::browsing, web::browser, works-with-format::html, x11::application
Section: web
Priority: optional
Filename: pool/main/c/chromium-browser/chromium-browser_37.0.2062.120-1~deb7u1_all.deb
Size: 171526
MD5sum: 58c6c6d6edc015001833642deecd22e1
SHA1: ed23c2239051424e200ef6fdffeacab5212ee162
SHA256: 0292de24f4ce92a02212fb618f7b26047f1062b0f7397cb8de04c66aa8780abc
```

I have spent hours on this, and I am out of ideas

```
root@mini210s:~# more /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian wheezy main
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chromium is only available on `amd64` and `i386` in Debian, so it can’t be installed on your mini210s. It used to be available on `armel` in Debian Squeeze, and for a while on `armhf`, but it was removed for Wheezy in March 2013, probably because it was too difficult to provide adequate security support on ARM platforms... See [the commit log](https://salsa.debian.org/chromium-team/chromium/commit/8761d73) for the exact removal (but there’s no more info than I’ve reproduced here).

Feel free to file a wishlist bug on `chromium` using `reportbug`, but be prepared to be asked to give a hand if you really want Chromium on your ARM device!